# tarfile can't open tgz

Tags: python, urllib, os.path, tarfile

I am trying to download tgz file from this website:
https://plg.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/gvcormac/foo07

here is my script:

```
import os
from six.moves import urllib
import tarfile

spam_path=os.path.join('ML', 'spam')
root_download='https://plg.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/gvcormac/foo07'
spam_url=root_download+'255 MB Corpus (trec07p.tgz)'

if not os.path.isdir(spam_path):
    os.makedirs(spam_path)

path=os.path.join(spam_path, 'trec07p.tgz')
if not os.path.isfile('trec07p.tgz'):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(spam_url,path)
tar_file=tarfile.open(path)
```

I am not sure what I am missing but the following error is returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ReadError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-5644813e0670> in <module>()
     18 if not os.path.isfile('trec07p.tgz'):
     19     urllib.request.urlretrieve(spam_url,path)
---> 20 tar_file=tarfile.open(path)
     21 # tar_file.extractall(path)
     22 # tar_file.close()

/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tarfile.pyc in open(cls, name, mode, fileobj, bufsize, **kwargs)
   1678                         fileobj.seek(saved_pos)
   1679                     continue
-> 1680             raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
   1681 
   1682         elif ":" in mode:

ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional parameters to [`tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open). You need to set the mode to `'r:gz'`.

```
tarfile.open(path, 'r:gz')
```

Working example after *Accept Agreement*:

```
import tarfile

import requests

URL = 'https://plg.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/gvcormac/trec07p.tgz'
FILE = '/home/blake/Downloads/trec07p.tgz'

resp = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
resp.raise_for_status()

with open(FILE, 'wb') as out_file:
    for line in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*4, decode_unicode=False):
        out_file.write(line)


f = tarfile.open(FILE, 'r:gz')
print(f.getnames())

f.close()
```

Output:

```
['trec07p/data/inmail.35059',
 'trec07p/data/inmail.34430',
 'trec07p/data/inmail.45722',
 ..
 ..]
```

Comment: I tried all modes 'r',  'r:*',  'r:',  'r:gz',  'r:bz2' but they all retuned error

Comment: It doesn't work because that site doesn't let you download their corpus automatically -- you have to click through an agreement. Your URL is bogus too. See edit.

Comment: @blakev I have the same problem. I downloaded the compressed file from the website but there is a problem in reading the compressed file by tarfile module.
So I don't think the problem relates to the website.