# Opening .tgz files with tarfile on Mac os X

Tags: python, macos, tarfile

I'm studying the book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow, and in the first project, as you probably know, it's going to deal with a housing dataset.

When I want to open the **housing.tgz** with **tarfile**, I get the error :`ReadError: file could not be opened successfully.`

**I'm a Mac OS user** and I searched a lot. But I couldn't find anyway to handle this problem. Even I tried the solution in [this question][1], but it didn't work. It seems that Mac cannot open .tgz files. Can anybody help?( I copied the codes from the book and there's no problem with the codes)

Thanks in advance!

**My code**:

````
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/tree/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"
def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    # os.makedirs(housing_path, exist_ok=True)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
fetch_housing_data()```


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651490/tarfile-cant-open-tgz
````

Comment: There should be no difference in opening the file in another OS. Please post the code you have that _isn't_ working, and we'll try to help you find the error.

Comment: I put the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using to download the archive does not seem to be correct; you are downloading a HTML file, hence the error. The correct URL would be: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/datasets/housing/housing.tgz - note the domain.

Comment: This link seems to be broken. now I get the error ```HTTP Error 404: Not Found```.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Indeed, the correct URL is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/.

Comment: Are you sure? I can click on the link above, my browser downloads the tarball, and I can open it and view the csv file. You can verify by going to the github repository in your browser, finding the file (the link you posted above), and clicking the download link. That is the URL that will work.